# Laravel any route with optional GET parameter

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 8.1. Currently I have this catch-all route:

`Route::any('/{any}', [IndexController::class, 'index'])->where('any', '.*');`

This works great for all URLs. However if I want to attach a GET parameter for ID, I have do this:

`/api/products/view?id=1`

Instead of that I want to do this:

`/api/products/view/1`

My function signature is like this:

`public function index(Request $request) {}`

I only want ID as an optional GET parameter.

Comment: Do you want to get the `id` from your `$request` or you want to make the `id` optional in your route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another optional route parameter and specify a pattern in the where for the `any` parameter - **".*"** will not work with optional parameter after any

```php
Route::any('/{any}/{id?}', [IndexController::class, 'index'])->where('any', '[A-Za-z-_]+');

public function index(Request $request) 
{
    $id = $request->route('id');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add another route param and get it in the Controller like I have below:

Route:

```
Route::any('/{any}/{id}', [IndexController::class, 'index'])->where('any', '.*');
```

Controller:

```
public function index($any, $id) 
{
    // $id will be passed in.
}
```